# javascript convert space to symbol in string

Tags: javascript

How to convert the space between letters into another character like "-"?

> SOLVED:
>
> For those who have the same problem:
>
> ```
> var namePicked = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
> var x = namePicked.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, "_").replace(/\s/g, "-");
> var y = x.split("").join(" ");
> ```
>
> this will turn John Smith (randomly chosen) into
>
> > _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _
>
> Nicely spaced out by "spaces", letters become underscores and spaces
>   become dashes. This is solved the "javascript" way. You can also do
>   this with loop for.

Here's my code **(before)**:

```
// list of names
var names = ["John Smith", "Joe Doe", "Ian Nobody", "James Black"];
var namePicked = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
var nameArray = new Array(namePicked.length);

window.onload = function() {
    //convert chosen name to array and replace letters with dashes
    for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
        nameArray[i] = "_";
    }
    //remove comma
    var nameHidden = nameArray.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = nameHidden;
}
```

I can only turn John Smith into a line of 10 underscores, I want to make it 4 `underscores` (first name) with a `dash` (for the space) before the last 5 `underscores` (last name). Also a `space` between each `underscore`. I'm sorry I didn't mention this earlier.
I've tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
        if (nameArray[i] == " ") {
            nameArray[i] = " ";
        }
        else {
            nameArray[i] = "_";
        }
    }
```

And some other variations but none works.

Comment: `names.map(name => name.split(' ').join('-'))`? That's a bit inefficient so you could use `name.replace(' ', '-')`.

Comment: Look at `replace()`.

Comment: `"John Smith".replace(/\s/g, '-').replace(/[^!-]/g, '_');` will give you `____-_____`. Or, with only one replace: `"John Smith".replace(/(\s)|([^!\s])/g, (m,s,l) => l?'_':'-');`, but it's harder to read

Comment: you could also do something like this: `str.split(" ").join("-");`

Comment: Please update your question and describe the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who has the same problem:

```
var namePicked = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
var x = namePicked.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, "_").replace(/\s/g, "-");
var y = x.split("").join(" ");
```

this will turn John Smith (randomly chosen) into

> _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _

Nicely spaced out by "spaces", letters become underscores and spaces become dashes.
This is solved the "javascript" way. You can also do this with loop for.

Answer (score 3):

You can chain `replace()` and `split()` to replace all non-whitespace characters with an underscore, and then replace the space between first and last names with a dash.

```js
var names = ["John Smith", "Joe Doe", "Ian Nobody", "James Black"];

var result = names.map(name => name.replace(/[^\s\\]/g, '_').split(' ').join('-'));
console.log(result);
```

If you want to space out the underscores, you can chain two more methods to this:

1. `replace()` every underscore with an underscore and space
2. `slice()` - to remove the last space

```js
var names = ["John Smith", "Joe Doe", "Ian Nobody", "James Black"];

var result = names.map(name => name.replace(/[^\s\\]/g, '_').split(' ').join('- ').replace(/[\_]/g, '_ ').slice(0, -1));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, Chava. Unfortunately, this will just print out a bunch of _ and - and they don't match the name generated.

Comment: @vietnguyen The amount of _ matches the amount of characters in the name.  However, since you want spaces between the underscores I added two things:  1) replace every `'_'` with `'_ '` (additional space after)  2) strip last character (extra space at end of string).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
    var names = ["John Smith", "Joe Doe", "Ian Nobody", "James Black"];
    var namePicked = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];


    window.onload = function () {
        var nameoutput = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < namePicked.length; i++) {
            if (namePicked[i] == " ") {
                nameoutput += " ";
            }
            else {
                nameoutput += "X";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = nameoutput;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ram. This works but it doesn't give me the space between the underscores. How would you do that?

Comment: Actually, I found out that adding a space after the - or _ will do the trick. However, I wonder if there's a better way to do that because adding a space will end up with a space at the end of the converted string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'map' method. The map method will literally 'map' a function call onto each element in the array, so you need to create array from your string with method split().

```js
var name = "John Smith";
var underscoredName = "";

name.split('').map(function(currentValue, index, nameString) {
  if (currentValue != " ") {
    underscoredName += "_";
  } else {
    underscoredName += "-";
  }
});

console.log(name); // John Smith
console.log(underscoredName); // ____-_____
```

Comment: Thank you blex and Ivan. This works. How would you add a space between each of the underscores and the dashes?

Comment: Actually, I found out that adding a space after the - or _ will do the trick. However, I wonder if there's a better way to do that because adding a space will end up with a space at the end of the converted string.

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert the space between letters into another character like "-"?

Well you know what you want to replace, you know what you wanna replace it with, now you just need to use replace :

`var new_str = old_str.replace(/ /g, "-");`

The RegEx `/ /g` means "every single space"

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all spaces to any other character using the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```
var replaced = test.replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

*Note that you have to assign the return value of `replace` to a variable.*

The `/\s/g` regular expression selects all spaces.

---

Here's an example of how you could apply it to your situation:

```js
var names = ["John Smith", "Joe Doe", "Ian Nobody", "James Black"];

console.log('names before: ', names);

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  names[i] = names[i].replace(/\s/g, '-');
}

console.log('names after: ', names);
```

Comment: Thanks Evans. Unless I missed something, I couldn't make your suggestion work.